# Stata: adding a number to a date variable

Tags: date, time, stata, clock

I am working with hospital admission data, where information on admission date and discharge date is stored in clock format %tcCCYY-NN-DD_hh:MM_AM, i.e. for example

```
  discharge date
2009-04-21 9:00 AM
```

So the data information is stored as milliseconds since January 1, 1960, and transforming this into a numeric double variable gives me

```
discharge date
1556269200000
```

Now, I would like to shift some of my date variables by 1 minute (just an example), and generate a new variable

```
gen new_discharge_date = discharge_date + 60*1000
```

This will only incidentally shift the discharge date by exactly one minute

In the example above this will instead give me

```
new_discharge_date 
2009-04-25 9:00 AM
```

or as double

```
new_discharge_date
 1556269236224
```

The difference between new_discharge_date and discharge_date is only 36224 milliseconds instead of 60000.

The problem occurs systematically, sometimes the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1960, will even be lower than before.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the timestamp should be stored in long and not double. Additionally try use some brackets: gen new_discharge_date = discharge_date + (60*1000)

Comment: Not so. `long` is inadequate here. See my answer. (Parentheses are fine but just cosmetic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary: Adding a constant to a date-time variable with units milliseconds creates another date-time variable. Both variables should be type `double`.

First note that clock is not a storage format in Stata. Clock date-time variables are **stored** as integers; clock format is a numeric display format, which is quite different. In fact the description in the original question is backwards: the date-time data arrive as strings, which are then converted to milliseconds with the `clock()` function.

You are correct that clock date-times should be stored as `double`s, as they are often very large integers, but for precisely that reason your shifted date-time (1 minute more than the original values) should not be stored in a `float`, which is what your `generate` does by default. You need to specify `double` in the `generate` statement. Using `float` instead just gives a crude approximation, which is why you observe errors. This is easy to check using your example as sandbox.

```
. clear

. set obs 1 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen s_discharge_date = "2009-04-21 9:00 AM"

. gen double discharge_date = clock(s_discharge_date, "YMD hm") 

. format discharge_date %tc 

. gen double new_discharge_date = discharge_date + 60*1000

. format new %tc

. gen long new_discharge_date2 = discharge_date + 60*1000

. format new_discharge_date2 %tc

. list 

     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
  1. |   s_discharge_date |     discharge_date | new_discharge_date |
     | 2009-04-21 9:00 AM | 21apr2009 09:00:00 | 21apr2009 09:01:00 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
     |                           new_di~2                           |
     |                                  .                           |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The advice given in a comment to use `long` is wrong, as the last experiment shows immediately. Fairly recent date-times have values in trillions, some orders of magnitude larger than be could held in a `long`. `help data types` shows the limits on values in various types.